# Performance issues tensorflow- M1 apple silicon chip

Tags: python, tensorflow, apple-m1

I am working with tensorflow in a macbook pro with the M1 chip. After (painfully) I managed to set up the proper invaronment and install the tensorflow mac following [this guide](https://github.com/mrdbourke/m1-machine-learning-test), I am now trying to fine tune a BERT model. My environment uses python 3.8 and I use Atom with hydrogen. The dataset I am working with is not public but I share a snippet of my code here:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoConfig, DataCollatorWithPadding
from transformers import TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification
from tensorflow.keras.losses import SparseCategoricalCrossentropy

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
    "bert-base-cased", padding='max_length', truncation=True)
def tokenize_function(example):
    return tokenizer(example["tidy_tweet"], truncation=True)

tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)

data_collator = DataCollatorWithPadding(
    tokenizer=tokenizer, return_tensors="tf")


tf_train_dataset = tokenized_datasets["train"].to_tf_dataset(
    columns=["attention_mask", "input_ids", "token_type_ids"],
    label_cols=["classify"],
    shuffle=True,
    collate_fn=data_collator,
    batch_size=8,
)
```

This last code reports `Metal device set to: Apple M1 Pro` from which I infer that the metal plug in has detected my chip properly.

Then when trying to fine tune the model:

```
model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    'bert-base-uncased', num_labels=2)


model.compile(
    optimizer="adam",
    loss=SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)
model.fit(
    tf_train_dataset,
    validation_data=tf_test_dataset,
)
```

The code is extremely slow and it takes more than 10 minutes to go over a single epoch. My training sample is about 3000 (worpiece tokenized) tweets. The ouput from the model is:

```
2022-03-05 16:12:39.271128: W tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:128] Failed to get CPU frequency: 0 Hz
2022-03-05 16:12:45.678284: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:113] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
2022-03-05 16:35:33.128057: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:113] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
503/503 [==============================] - 1489s 3s/step - loss: 0.6477 - accuracy: 0.6802 - val_loss: 0.6198 - val_accuracy: 0.69

<keras.callbacks.History at 0x3910c0e50>
```

Is this time normal? I was running some trials on bigger datasets in google collab and I was able to run several epochs much faster. Also, every time I've tried to fit the model I receive an internal warning saying that **my system has run out of application memory**. How is this possible?

Another issue is that all the predictions obtain from the model are exactly the same...

```
preds = model.predict(tf_test_dataset)["logits"]
```

outputs:

```
array([[ 0.40131712, -0.30243358],
   [ 0.40131715, -0.3024336 ],
   [ 0.40131712, -0.30243355],
   ...,
   [ 0.40131715, -0.30243358],
   [ 0.40131712, -0.30243355],
   [ 0.40131715, -0.30243355]], dtype=float32)
```